# How to use TableViewDelegate and TableViewDataSource in cell another TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I try to use `TableViewDelegate` and `TableViewDataSource` in cell for tableView in another `tableView`. But cellForRowAtIndexPath didn't called. What's a problem.

```
class RequesterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var delegate: RequesterTableViewCellDelegate?

var serviceRequestCardItem: ServiceRequestCard?

@IBOutlet weak var tvIssues: UITableView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.tvIssues.tag = tagOfIssueTableView
    self.tvIssues.delegate = self
    self.tvIssues.dataSource = self
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


@IBAction func bActivatedmenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    if delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.selectedCellForDelete(self)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var countOfIssues: Int = 0
    if let issues = serviceRequestCardItem?.getDateEquipment()?.getIssues()?.count {
        countOfIssues = issues
    }
    return countOfIssues
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(IssueCell.reuseIdentifer(), forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let issue = serviceRequestCardItem!.getDateEquipment()?.getIssues()![indexPath.row]
    if tableView.tag == tagOfIssueTableView {
        if let lState = (cell as! IssueCell).lIssueState {
            lState.text = issue?.getIssueState()?.getName()
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

}
```

//creating cell in tableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    let serviceRequestCardItem = serviceRequestCardArray[indexPath.row]
    var requesterCell: RequesterTableViewCell! = nil
    if tableView.tag == tagOfRequestTableView {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(RequesterTableViewCell.reuseIdentifer(), forIndexPath: indexPath)
        requesterCell = (cell as! RequesterTableViewCell)
        requesterCell.delegate = self
        requesterCell.setDataForTableView(serviceRequestCardItem)
        requesterCell.selectedCell(serviceRequestCardItem)
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are creating `RequesterTableViewCell` in tableView

Comment: Completed there

Comment: if numberOfRowsInSection is called then cellForRowAtIndexPath not means check cell count return..if its 0 it wont call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I am at screen see that i have a cell. I think problem is that i use this methods in tableViewCell

Comment: You are all right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two variables (outlets) which will be connected with your table views. For example:

```
var tableViewOne: UITableView?
var tableViewTwo: UITableView?
```

the in for example this method use like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if tableView == tableViewOne {
    return 5
}

if tableView == tableViewTwo {
    return 1
}
}
```

using this pattern you need to fill rest of required methods for `table view`

Comment: it's not problem. Problem that cellForRowAtIndexPath didn't called

Comment: do you cast call `as!` a class which you defined before? Like `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(IssueCell.reuseIdentifer(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass`? If you create a default cell in interface builder it can not work because reference to specific object in cell has only one table view. If You want to do it for both, you need to create Custom Cell programatically.

Comment: Yes. I have tableView in cell another tableView, and i have to try use protocols of tableView in TableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You can either :-

- set the `noOfValues` that you will return in `numberOfRowsInSection` in `cellForIndexPath` function of your parentTableViewCell..

  Declare a variable
      `var noOfValues : Int!` in `RequesterTableViewCell`

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(RequesterTableViewCell.reuseIdentifer(), forIndexPath: indexPath)
       cell.noOfValues = serviceRequestCardItem?.getDateEquipment()?.getIssues()?.count
       ...}
  ```

And in `RequesterTableViewCell`:-

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return noOfValues
    }
```

- reload the data when you have your issues retrieved, as far as i can tell your `return` statement is being executed even before you are able to set the count

Just change `numberOfRowsInSection` in your code:-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
var countOfIssues: Int = 0
if let issues = serviceRequestCardItem?.getDateEquipment()?.getIssues()?.count {
    countOfIssues = issues
    tvIssues.reloadData() 
      }
return countOfIssues
}
```

Comment: don't work because issues at another scope of this function. Error missing return Int

Comment: NumberOfRowsInSection return correct value. But cellForRowAtIndexPath don't called. And now i have a warning "could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available" tvIssues.reloadData() string